# How do I keep my Async method thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, win-universal-app, iot

I need to write a method in my Windows Universal App to write to the SD card.  How can I ensure two threads do not try to write to the same file at the same time in my method below ?

```
public async void WriteToCard(string strFileName, IEnumerable<string> listLinesToWrite)
{
    IStorageItem item = await folder.GetItemAsync(strFileName);
    StorageFile file = (StorageFile)item;

    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, listLinesToWrite);
}
```

Comment: easiest way: write one after the other (most likely you will not get much quicker if you try to write in parallel anyways) - if not you have to take care of it yourself (no way to give good advicel from this snippet)

Comment: Carsten - I'm not looking for a performance boost.  My concern is this method being called twice on the same file.  I will edit my question with the code I used in my old app where I used a lock.  It's my understanding you should not use a lock in an async method.

Comment: yes they are tricky to use (as dcastr said there are some) - I would just queue all writes up and write them one after the other (there are prebuild things in TPL-dataflow and you will surely find something if you look for *agents* - but of course you can just use `Queue`, `ConcurrentQueue`, ...)

Comment: @Carsten is probably referring to the `ActionBlock<T>` when he mentioned the TPL Dataflow lib.

Comment: yes that's it (I never remember as you have better options in F# ;) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keep a map with a `ConcurrentDictionary` which maps each file to a `SemaphoreSlim`. Then, fetch each semaphore based on the file location you'll be writing to:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> fileLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();

public async Task WriteToCardAsync(string strFileName, IEnumerable<string> listLinesToWrite)
{
   var semaphoreSlim = fileLocks.GetOrAdd(strFileName, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));

   await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
   try
   {
       IStorageItem item = await folder.GetItemAsync(strFileName);
       StorageFile file = (StorageFile)item;

       await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, listLinesToWrite);
   }
   finally
   {
       semaphoreSlim.Release();
   }
}
```

Side note - Use `async Task` instead of `async void`. I also added the `Async` postfix to the methods.

Comment: You don't actually need the `Lazy` here.  Having the dictionary map directly to the semaphores would be fine.  If you're worried about creating additional semaphores (which shouldn't be a large concern, but still) simply use the overload of `GetOrAdd` that takes a factory delegate, rather than an object itself.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov  Thanks for the nice answer.  Is the purpose of Lazy<SemaphoreSlim> to prevent the creation of the ConcurrentDictionary until needed to save on resources ?

Comment: @BillGreer The dictionary is created as soon as this class is used for the first time, so that has no bearing on it.

Comment: Just trying to get my head wrapped around Lazy.  I looked at the MSDN documentation but I'm still confused :)

Comment: @BillGreer Like I said in my first comment; it's superfluous in this case.  It's not harmful, it's just not accomplishing anything important.

Comment: @Servy I remembered `valueFactory` (in `ConcurrentDictionary` methods) had the side-effect of running the delegate multiple times. Wasn't sure of that was the case here.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's not guaranteed to not run it multiple times, although it doesn't *always* run multiple times for each key, but as the object in question here doesn't cause side effects on construction, nor is it particularly expensive to construct, that's not a problem at all.  Like I said in my first comment, if you create a few extra semaphores that you throw away it's just not a big deal.

Comment: @Servy I guess it's probably not that meaningful here then.

Comment: @Bill The objects in the dictionary will only be created once you start initializing them when running the method. The minor advantage here is that `SemaphoreSlim` comes OOTB for WP8.1, instead of getting a NuGet package. That's the only difference. `Lazy` wasn't needed here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) library, which contains an [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock)

Assuming there won't be a huge number of filenames, you can use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to associate a filename to a lock - otherwise, the dictionary size might grow unbound.

```
private readonly locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLock>();

public async void WriteToCard(string strFileName, IEnumerable<string> listLinesToWrite)
{
    var lock = locks.GetOrAdd(strFileName, () => new AsyncLock());

    using (await lock.LockAsync())
    {
        IStorageItem item = await folder.GetItemAsync(strFileName);
        StorageFile file = (StorageFile)item;

        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, listLinesToWrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will only allow to write one *thread* to write to one file at any time ... so just the same as just doing them in an old fashioned for loop ...

Comment: @Carsten That assumes the writes are being done in a deterministic order, by the same thread. In which case, no synchronization is needed whatsoever, and the question has no meaning. If the writes are being done in a non-deterministic fashion by multiple threads, then this is needed.

Comment: I can only guess because it's not 100% clear - but I think he wants to write to multiple different files (maybe to the same more than once) - so you only have to watch out that you don't write to the same file at the same time - the rest could possible be worked from a few parallel threads

Comment: @Brandon that is exactly what I was trying to say

Comment: I will not be writing to a bunch of files at the same time.  I just want to make sure my method does not try to write to the same file from two different calls / threads.  I think dcastro's code snippet solves my problem.

Comment: There's no need to be worried about millions of files as long as you just use weak references for the keys. ConditionalWeakTable is a standard option, but has list performance which might become a bottleneck (there might be standard solutions by now that don't have this downside), but at least you don't have a memory leak.